# Java class placeholder (OpenGL on different devices)

Tags: java, class, opengl, interface

I want to use different openGL environments in my application.

I am developing a game app, but testing it all on windows, because it's easier to run. I am using GL2 for windows, GLES for android. My idea is to limit platform dependencies on certain files which would act as "interfaces". From the rest of the code I would use these classes. I will only use functions of GL2 and GLES which exist in both libraries.

Note that GL2 is an interface itself and can be implemented by different classes.

My first guess was to simply create an interface (PlatformGL) which is equal to GL2 and cast the GL2 to it. The definition of PlatformGL would then be in a file which exists in one version per platform, but it won't cast the received GL2 to PlatformGL:

```
public interface PlatformGL extends GL2{
}
```

Or directly based on the implementation of GL2 (not preferred):

```
public class PlatformGL extends jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl{
    public PlatformGL(GLProfile prof, GLContextImpl cont){
        super(prof, cont);
    }
}
```

In both cases I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl cannot be cast to [...].PlatformGL
```

One option would be to build a new class passing all function calls to its underlying GL, but GL has a lot of functions and variables, and I don't want to write all of them down. It would probably be the cleanest version, as some functions with different name conventions could be passed through to the right function.

Do you have any ideas other than using a preprocessor to replace the class name?

Is there a class in java to store classes in? Something like

```
<class> mygl = GLES;

[...]
mygl gl = (mygl) getGL();
gl.glEnable(mygl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I hope you have an idea of how to do this.

Comment: I know it's not answering your question but if you want to write OpenGL once and have it work on Windows and Android then LibGDX is very good. They write their own GL10 (and GL11, GL20) interface and then for each platform they implement that. http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/